# Laravel Передать данные по ссылке в контроллер

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование

проблема следующая: мне необходимо, чтобы по клику на ссылку пользователь мог скачать файл, для этого в rout и мне надо передать ID файла, чтобы тот передал его в контроллер. Вопрос, как передать переменную в rout?

HTML

```html
<div class="subpage_table">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Наименование файла</td>
          <td>Дата загрузки</td>
          <td>Размер файла</td>
          <td>Пользователь</td>
          <td>Скачать</td>
        </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach ($journal as $record)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$record->Name}}</td>
            <td>{{date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime($record->DateInsert))}}</td>
            <td>{{round(($record->Size),2)}} Кб</td>
            <td>{{$record->user}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{route('download')}}" download><button><div class="download"></div></button></a></td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Rout 
`Route::get('download/{file_id}','Upload@download')->name('download');`

Controller (не добит)

```
    public function download($file_id){
        $query = DB::table('FileJournal')->where('ID', $file_id))->first();
        $file = pg_unescape_bytea($query->File);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lalka.docx');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($file));
        echo $file;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route)
Если роут принимает параметры, вы можете передать их вторым аргументом:

```
$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);
```

По-умолчанию функция route генерирует абсолютный URL-адрес. Если вы хотите сгенерировать относительный URL-адрес, можно передать false в качестве третьего параметра:

```
$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1], false);
```